Questions about Chinese language on MacOSX
Is it appropriate to post a self-answered question that is meant to share a useful tip with Chinese language learners? For example I have found a number of useful Chinese dictionaries that could be downloaded to MacOSX for free. I also have learned tips on:

Typing PinYin in MacOSX
Enabling Mandarin (China/Taiwan) and Cantonese Speech on MacOSX

I believe sharing this information would be useful to others learning Chinese but I would appreciate comments on how to structure such tips within the context of the Chinese Language site.

There is already an answer regarding OS X by me even if the question was about Windows. :D It covers both the typing and the "stylus-like" writing. You could answer however for the Windows part, I think.
What do you mean exactly about the second point? Do you mean the system language?

I've put a complete guide including the answers to both points onto my profile. Basically, I was wondering where to place the information and I decided to upload to Github and provide a demo of the advanced feature set.
